# Good pretrained convolutional neural network for a monochromatic image

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

For an image recognition task one may use a pretrained convolutional neural network (like `VGG` or `GoogLeNet`). They usually work great - but with one assumption - only for RGB images. I'm looking for a good pretrained neural network which was trained on a monochromatic images. Does anyone know something like this?

Comment: Use a [CNN](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports2016/202_Report.pdf) to colorize the grayscale image first ;-) No, just joking... Interesting question - though I don't think you will find an answer here on stackoverflow, as "please find me a book/tutorial/..." are not well received and usually closed.

Comment: Maybe you will get an answer on DataScience.SE - it seems to me that they are quite open to such questions, though maybe you should check if it is on-topic there first. I found a [similar question](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12717/convert-filters-pre-trained-with-imagenet-to-grayscale) there, though the answer is probably not what you were hoping for.

Comment: Transferring monochromatic image into RGB without changes colors does not work?